# formulario auto-populado com os restantes dados de um dos campos selecionados

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Queria ter um formulário dinâmico em que a única coisa que se pede é a seleção de um utilizador u de uma lista de utilizadores passada para do model apartir de um controlador, os campos email e estado devem ser automaticamente exibidos dependendo do utilizador que esteja selecionado.

o objeto utilizador tem a seguinte classe:

```
public class Utilizador{
  private String perfil;
  private String email;
  private string estado;

  ...
}
```

os elementos do formulário estao organizados da seguinte forma:

```
<dl th:class="form-group">
  <dt>perfil:</dt>
  <dd>
     <select class="form-control" th:field="*{hhFrom}">
        <option th:each=" u : ${utilizadores}" th:value="" 
             th:text="${u.perfil}">Options
        </option>
     </select> 
  </dd>
  <dt>email:</dt>
  <dd th:text="${u.email}></dd>
  <dt>estado:</dt>
  <dd th:text="${u.estado}></dd>
</dl>
```

estou ciente que th:text="${u.email} e th:text="${u.estado} estão a apontar p um objeto do tipo utilizador que não é visivel no lugar onde se encontram, mas o meu objetivo era que se possa contornar de alguma forma este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o {$utilizadores} para um array (caso não estiver) e então trabalhar com o INDEX como se fosse um ID utilizando `<option value="index">Nome do perfil</option>` e então chamar a alteração com `$('selector').change(function() {...})`

Ficaria assim:

```js
$('document').ready(function () {
  // Apenas para o exemplo
  class Utilizador {
    constructor(perfil, email, estado) {
      this.perfil = perfil;
      this.email = email;
      this.estado = estado;
    }
  }

  var utilizadores = Array(2); // Array com os utilizadores
  utilizadores[0] = new Utilizador("Fulano", "fulano@gmail.com", "SP");
  utilizadores[1] = new Utilizador("Ciclano", "ciclano@live.com", "RJ");
  // Apenas para o exemplo

//Loop no array para criar um option com value=(INDEX do array) e com texto=(Perfil)
  for (var i = 0; i < utilizadores.length; i++) {
    $('#perfil').append("<option value=" + i + ">" + utilizadores[i].perfil + "</option>");
  }

//Buscar o utilizador pelo INDEX do array
  function updateFields(i) {
    if (i == -1) {
      $('#email').text("");
      $('#estado').text("");
    } else {
      $('#email').text(utilizadores[i].email);
      $('#estado').text(utilizadores[i].estado);
    }
  }

  $('#perfil').change(function () {
    var i = $(this).find(":selected").val(); // i = value do option selectionado
    updateFields(i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl th:class="form-group">
  <dt>perfil:</dt>
  <dd>
     <select class="form-control" th:field="*{hhFrom}" id="perfil">
  <option value="-1">Selecione um perfil</option>
     </select> 
  </dd>
  <dt>email:</dt>
  <dd id="email"></dd>
  <dt>estado:</dt>
  <dd id="estado"></dd>
</dl>
```